# Shopify: How To Change The Background Color Of The Product Page According To Different Variation?

Tags: javascript, css, shopify

I'm currently working on my product page, where all variation options are displayed on a single page. I would like to change the background color of the page based on the selected Flavor.

For example, when one flavor is selected, the bg color changes smoothly to the flavor's picture bg color. Here's the link: https://www.yak9chews.com/collections/yak9-chews/products/test-all-chews-and-flavors?variant=4202493

I'm thinking the basic idea is to use a conditional structure like this:

```
if (variation == variationNumber) {
    bgColor = "someColorHex";
} else if (variation == variationNumber1) {
    bgColor = "someColorHex2";
} else {  // rest of conditions cases
    bgColor = default;
}
```

However, I'm not certain about this approach. I've been struggling with this issue for a month now and would appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Comment: use switch statement by variation like `switch(variation){ case 'yak: bgColor = "someColorHex2"; break; ... all cases then default value}`

Comment: Or you can use an object with key and value map for different variation colors. If you like I can post an answer, but the solution is simple so I don't see the necessity of an answer, for a similar problem lookup the switch statement in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75669481/how-to-dynamically-style-reactjs-components-based-on-changing-data/75669656#75669656). It's a similar problem that requires dynamic styling  except in your case, you only need background color values.